# Unity - Mac build starts up really slow, but everything runs fine in editor

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity project on a mac. When running in editor, everything starts and runs smoothly, but when running a standalone mac build, the application hangs for 15 seconds before running properly. After the initial wait, everything runs as expected.

I'm using Unity 2017.1.1f, but this happened before on Unity 5.6.2f too. The problem appears on multiple computers and I've tried to remove all app preferences and files in Library/Application Support and Library/Preferences. I also tried to set quality settings to very low, disable logging, and disable v-sync. The problem persists on new blank projects as well.

The Unity profiler shows the following after the startup:
[image: Unity profiler]

There is a 5 second wait in Application.LoadLevelAsync Integrate, another at SwitchToStandaloneSettings -> SetResolutionImmediate, and some unaccounted time as well.

Comment: I have the same problem with the OS X build. Very slow boot and the first animations in my entry scene. Then everything runs as expected. The same project run smoothly on iOS and Windows.